# excel copy values of cell if particular cell in same row is not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have column A with first and last name of a person, column B with place of birth(not important in this case) and column C with employment date.
Column C can be empty.
I would like to copy values of column A and column C to another sheet IF column C is not empty.
And i would like it to be dynamic, so if i add new person with employment date to first sheet, it will be added to second one
Hint please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference across Sheets, but you will need the correct syntax.

So, set up your first Sheet.

[image]

Then, on the second Sheet set up what data you want to replicate (based on the employment date being true).

[image]

You can create a similar condition for A2 to fill in the Name of employee.
When these two cell formulas are ready, you can simply copy down the page for an estimated range of employees you may have.

[image]

There will be visible gaps between the active data that have employment dates, and those rows that don't. You can then highlight the Sheet 2 columns (A+B) and activate the Data -> Filtering, so that your data can be manipulated. I then would select "Sort A->Z", which will remove the white-space between lines (and order the start dates in sequence).

[image]

On an update to Sheet 1, the data is transferred automatically to Sheet 2, but you may just need to re-sort the list, using the automatic (filtering) pull-down menu options.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a straightforward IF statement. In the column you want the values to be "copied" to in the second sheet:

`=IF(C1<>"", A1, "")`

Then autofill down. Note that the second sheet will likely have a sparse list, rows will be empty when the corresponding row in the first sheet has an empty C column.

However if you want a contiguous list I'd take a look at another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013461/excel-expression-to-copy-rows-but-remove-blank-rows) and just modify the ranges and condition to meet your needs.